# iOS Crash Report on Reported Thread

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault

This is a follow up to a previous question I'd asked about troubleshooting a crash log:
" [NSAutoReleasePool releasing view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753087/nsautoreleasepool-releasing-view-controller) "

That question was answered adequately, but I now have a slightly different question. If you look at the full crash log:
https://gist.github.com/joelmartinez/dc2e94f0b3c554a0a384

It actually states that the crash occurred at Thread 0:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0
```

So my question then is, considering the only user code is in Thread 7, is it fair to assume that that's the true cause of the crash? or has that just sent me on a wild goose chase? I've still been unable to reproduce this crash so any other tips anyone could offer from looking at that crash log would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have a symbolicated version of the crash?

Comment: What do think should be retaining your view controller on thread 0?

Comment: @thegrinner that is the symbolicated version of the crash. Is there a way to symbolicate the system libraries in addition to my user code?

Comment: Connect something that's the same device model to your Mac - XCode should slurp the system library offsets automatically. Then resymbolicate.

Comment: You need the symbols of the iOS Version and CPU architecture of the device that created the crash. You could also post the complete crash report (with header and binary images section) in the gist, then others could symbolicate the rest.